# Dropdown menu not show()-ing sometimes in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu on http://www.idataresearch.com that displays when the document is finished loading in order to avoid the content shown without css/js problem that occurs as the page is loading.  This seems to work great in all browsers except Internet Explorer.  Quite often the menu just doesn't show up at all and I have to refresh the page in order to get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the non-working document-ready function (I've since changed it back to the way I had it because it actually made things worse in that sometimes the menu would just be stuck open):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
    orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})

  jQuery('#smoothmenu1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is the code you are talking about

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ddsmoothmenu.init({
        mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
        orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
        classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
        //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
        contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
    })
</script>
```

There is nothing stopping this code from being run before the page is completed loading.  I would suggest you place this code (and a lot of your other scripts) into a `$(document).ready()` function.

This is in word press, I beleive, which is not my area of expertise, but I think that should help the issue.

Comment: I did this with no charnge.  I already have the div containing the menu inside a document.ready function.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, can you edit the post to show your document ready function?  The script I've posted here is on the page in such a way that it runs as soon as the browser sees it.

Comment: Check out my edit.  Plus you can just look at the source.  This is the problem I'm having.  It is supposed to run after document load (like I have above) but it doesn't actually load (unless I refresh the page).

Comment: OK I see that you've moved it all down to a load function.  I don't think the Dynamic Drive menu works on a "Show" command like you think.  The "smoothmenu" unordered list is already visible, that's why you aren't seeing a change.  Try putting this in and you will see what I mean `jQuery('#smoothmenu1').hide();`  What you need to figure out is which sub-menu you want to show, and show that.  Something like `jQuery('#aboutus').fadeIn();`

Comment: Ok, I think you're missing the point of my problem. The dropdown menu works just fine.  The problem I had before with it is that as the page is loading, before the javascript is loaded, the menu displays open for a second or so, which looks bad. So, I wanted to hide the menu until the page loads.  This works on all browsers except IE.  It seems like IE doesn't like something else to do with the page, causing the document ready function to not fire.  However, it seems to be random in that a lot of the time it works.  I turned degugging on in IE and it doesn't show anything ...

Comment: Ah, you are right, I was misunderstanding!  This might be fixable with CSS.  `#smoothmenu1 ul li ul {display: none}` at the CSS level should stop them from being rendered, originally, but then should be overridden by the javascript to make them visible.  Right now they are all being updated to display:none by inline styles from the javascript.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with invalid html and IE.  I fixed all the code and it now works.